# Herkunft von »vermöbeln«

Tags: verb, etymology, colloquial

*Vermöbeln* ist – zumindest in Deutschland – eine umgangssprachliche Umschreibung von *zusammenschlagen, krankenhausreif schlagen,* usw.

Ich frage mich, woher das Wort kommt. Ähnlich gebildete Verben wie *verwässern* oder *versalzen* bezeichnen das Hinzufügen von übermäßigen Mengen des Stammsubstantivs, was zu einem unerwünschten Effekt führt. Aber wenn ich vermöbelt werde, wird mir üblicherweise kein Möbel zugefügt – meistens sind es Fäuste und Fußtritte, gelegentlich auch Hilfsmittel wie Baseballschläger, die auf mich eindreschen. Und auch der Endzustand nach dem Vermöbeln erscheint mir nicht wirklich analog zum Endzustand nach einer Versalzung.

Gut, es gibt auch eine zweite Gruppe ähnlich gebildeter Verben: solche wie *verseifen*. Das bezeichnet ursprünglich den Prozess der Herstellung von Seife aus tierischen oder pflanzlichen Fetten, und in der Chemie darüberhinaus eine ähnliche Reaktion. Aber auch hier: Wenn ich vermöbelt werde, werde ich anschließend üblicherweise nicht an die Wand gestellt um irgendeine Funktion im Zimmer wie das Aufbewahren von Büchern zu übernehmen.

Woher stammt also *vermöbeln* und wie erklärt sich dessen Bedeutung?

Comment: Du sollst auch nicht an ein Ikearegal, sondern an einen Polstersessel oder ein *Sopha* (aus Grimm's Wörterbuch, der Eintrag bei *vermöbeln*: "wol einen wie ein hausgerät (stuhl, sopha) durchklopfen") denken...

Comment: @tofro Tja, Generation Sechskant …

Comment: http://9gag.com/gag/6961604/a-high-five-in-the-face

Answer (score 5):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vermoebeln) hieß "vermöbeln" ursprünglich etwas wie "vergeuden" oder "verschleudern". Der Ursprung liegt wohl in Auktionen, bei denen Möbel für (zu) wenig Geld unter die Leute gebracht wurden.

Wie die Bedeutung auf "jemanden völlig verprügeln" überging, kann ich nur spekulieren. Ich halte es aber für vorstellbar, dass es um die Chancenlosigkeit des Opfers geht. Wer "vermöbelt" wird, hat kaum bis keine Chancen sich zu wehren, er wird quasi "unter Wert" im Kampf besiegt - wie die Möbel bei den Auktionen oft unter Wert losgeschlagen wurden.

Im Internet findet man auch andere Erklärungsansätze. Beispielsweise sollen die Verteidiger einer belagerten Festung oder Stadt, wenn sie alle anderen Möglichkeiten ausgeschöpft hatten, die Angreifer auch schon mal mit dem Mobiliar beworfen haben. Ein anderer Ansatz ist, dass man früher (Polster-)Möbel "ausgeklopft" oder "ausgeschlagen" habe, ähnlich wie Teppiche, um sie vom Staub zu befreien. Diese Ansätze erscheinen mir jedoch weniger belastbar, deshalb verlinke ich auch keine Quellen dazu.

Comment: Ich finde eigentlich die Herkunft vom "Sessel ausklopfen" gar nicht so unplausibel.

Comment: Nicht nur du musst spekulieren, auch die Sprachwissenschaftler scheinen sich unsicher zu sein. Grimms Wörterbuch meint: "wol einen wie ein hausgerät (stuhl, sopha) durchklopfen" http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV02798#XGV02798 Kluge (2011) meint: "[v]ermutlich über die Bedeutung 'polieren', vgl. aufmöbeln", und unter "aufmöbeln" findet sich dann die Bedeutung "alte Möbel auffrischen". Gemeint ist mit dem Verweis auf "polieren" dessen Gebrauch in Wendungen wie "die Fresse polieren" für "schlagen, verprügeln".

Comment: @what Das mit *aufmöbeln* klingt auch interessant und plausibel!

Answer (score 4):

Eine ganz andere unbestätigte Theorie wäre: Könnte es vielleicht um eine Fehlübersetzung aus einer anderen Sprache handeln? Die eigentliche Meinung wäre dann "ummöblieren" was man in manchen Sprachen sagt. Z.B in Englisch "rearrange (ones face)" und in Schwedisch "möblera om". D.h man hat die Absicht jemandens Nase zu plazieren wo das Auge gehört und die Zähne in den Schlund.

Answer (score -1):

Bei einer Führung durch die schöne Stadt Lüneburg im Jahr 2020 wurde folgendes zum Thema "vermöbeln" berichtet:

> Bei Angriffen auf die Stadt wurden Eindringlinge in enge Gassen getrieben und diese dann mit Eisenstangen abgesperrt. Die Feinde, die sich in der Gasse befanden, konnten weder vor noch zurück. Dann haben die Bewohner der Stadt ihre Fenster ausgerissen und die Freunde mit allem was sie hatten, beworfen. Es flogen auch Möbelstücke auf die Feinde - somit festigte sich der Begriff "vermöbeln".

Comment: Hast Du dazu bitte die Quelle, einen Link?

Answer (score -2):

Ich denke, dass sich *vermöbeln* auf das Töten einer Kuh bezieht, man vermöbelt eine Kuh und macht aus dem Leder Möbel.